# Extracting variables from data printed to screen

Tags: python

I am working on older code, oldCode.py Basically it prints to screen some data, like the sales of items 1,2 and 3.

print '1 500'
   print '2 842'
   print '3 734'

I want to extract this data for further processing.  I know I can stop python from printing this information to the screen, and make it write the information to some file output.dat by writing

```
python oldCode.py >> output.dat
```

However, in the first place how do I even extract the data to process from output.dat when that isn't defined in the script in the first place? And I have to write the results of my processing step to the same output file. Short of rewriting the entire code (final option), how will I be able to do this?

Comment: Serialize your data. JSON should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can redirect stdout to a file by adding something like this to your code.

```
import sys

# This sets the normal system print output to a variable
# in case you need to restore it later in the script.
normal_stdout = sys.stdout

# This redirects the print output to a file.
sys.stdout = open('output.dat','w')

#do stuff

# And to change it back for new code, in case you actually want to print
sys.stdout = normal_stdout
```

Please keep in mind that anything that prints to the console, including Tracebacks, will be printed to the file. You can open this file and read the information inside without much difficulty.

Best practice would be to do one of two things:
1) If you are adding to the old code, modify it by assigning to a variable or appending to a dictionary or similar object, which you can use elsewhere for further processing, either alongside or instead of a print statement.
2) If your code is referencing the other code, import it at the top of your code

```
 import oldCode.py
```

and modify the old code to return rather than print. To do this, you'll probably have to make similar changes to those described above in 1) so that you have something to return. To know the best route to take, we would have to see your old code, or at least a stripped down version.